# React Native Link/Icon Style

Tags: react-native

I am using `create-react-native-app` to build an android app. I have a `Nav` component and using `{Link}` from `react-router-native` and `Icon` from `react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons`. My issue is when I press one of the `<Link/>` it gives itself a black background color temporarily.

How do I manipulate this? Either get rid of the black background color when I click on it or make it display a different color?

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import {Link} from 'react-router-native';

export default class Nav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.nav}>

        <Link to='/'>
          <Icon name="home" style={styles.icon} size={35}/>
        </Link>

        <Link to='/add'>
          <Icon name="add" style={styles.icon} size={35}/>
        </Link>

        <Link to='/view'>
          <Icon name="list" style={styles.icon} size={35}/>
        </Link>

        <Link to='/about'>
          <Icon name="help" style={styles.icon} size={35}/>
        </Link>

      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  nav: {
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'space-around',
    flexDirection:'row',
  },
  icon: {
    height:35,
    color:'white',
  },
  link: {
    flex:1
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

React-native-router's [`Link`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-native/Link.js) is built using react-native's [`TouchableHighlight`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight) as its main component so we can use the same properties.

> How do I manipulate this? Either get rid of the black background color when I click on it or make it display a different color?

Set the `underlayColor` to clear

```
<Link to='/' underlayColor="transparent">
    <Icon name="home" style={styles.icon} size={35}/>
</Link>
```

or to any color with an opacity of 0

```
<Link to='/' underlayColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)">
    <Icon name="home" style={styles.icon} size={35}/>
</Link>
```

or to any color you like

```
<Link to='/' underlayColor="rgba(55, 155, 255, 1)">
    <Icon name="home" style={styles.icon} size={35}/>
</Link>
```